# Environment variables in project are all wrong/different

Tags: bash, environment-variables, android, macos, api

I'm not an expert nor very proficient in OS and shell commands, and that's why I've come for help. I was successfully storing my API Keys for my Flutter project as Environment Variables, until I had problems (unrelated to env) and had to reinstall the Flutter SDK. The Flutter SDK is now in a different folder and I've changed my PATH to include that so no problems creating and running a project.

If I call `$**printenv**` in ANY terminal session, it prints this as it should(excluded some pairs, but all defaults are there):

```
BEAR_TOKEN=*********
SDKMAN_CURRENT_API=https://api.sdkman.io/2
USER=<user>
SDKMAN_LEGACY_API=https://api.sdkman.io/1
PATH=/Users/<user>/.sdkman/candidates/kotlin/current/bin:/Users/<user>/Dev/Flutter/flutter/bin:/Users/<user>/.pub-cache/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/<user>/Desktop/android:
PWD=/Users/<user>
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SDKMAN_VERSION=5.6.1+290
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
HOME=/Users/<user>
SDKMAN_DIR=/Users/<user>/.sdkman
SDKMAN_CANDIDATES_DIR=/Users/<user>/.sdkman/candidates
RAPID_API_KEY=***************
```

However, now when I print my environment through source code in my app, it prints:

```
PATH:/sbin:/system/sbin:/product/bin:/apex/com.android.runtime/bin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/odm/bin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin,
ANDROID_BOOTLOGO: 1, 
ANDROID_ROOT: /system, 
ANDROID_ASSETS: /system/app, 
ANDROID_DATA: /data, 
ANDROID_STORAGE: /storage, 
ANDROID_RUNTIME_ROOT: /apex/com.android.runtime, 
ANDROID_TZDATA_ROOT: /apex/com.android.tzdata, 
EXTERNAL_STORAGE: /sdcard, 
ASEC_MOUNTPOINT: /mnt/asec, 
BOOTCLASSPATH: /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/android.test.base.jar:/apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar:/apex/com.android.media/javalib/updatable-media.jar, 
DEX2OATBOOTCLASSPATH: /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/cor
```

So these are obviously very different environments, hence why I cannot even access my API Keys in my Flutter app. It seems to only be affecting Flutter projects. Can anyone help me sort of "redirect" or correct my environment? I have no idea how this happened but I've exhausted all options to the best of MY knowledge. I am running MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6.

EDIT: I am running my project through terminal (IDE terminal window, and Terminal app).

Thank you!

Comment: Process inherit environment from their parent process. Are you running flutter apps from the terminal or from IDE or something like that?